# Internet Explorer 11 losing cookie of iframe embedded website when link target is "_blank" - same domain, different subdomain

Tags: php, cookies, iframe, internet-explorer-11, session-cookies

When embedding `https://subdomain-b.example.com` with an `iframe` on `https://subdomain-a.example.com` and then clicking a link within the `iframe` that opens in a new tab/window the cookie gets lost.

I am not sure if it has anything to do with it, but everything is strictly `https`.

Code on https://subdomain-a.example.com:

```
<iframe src="subdomain-b.example.com/index.php"></iframe>
```

Code on https://subdomain-b.example.com/index.php: Important that the link opens in _blank

```
<?php
setcookie("TestCookie", "someValue");
?>
<a href="showcookie.php" target="_blank">link</a>
```

Code on https://subdomain-b.example.com/showcookie.php:

```
<?php
print_r($_COOKIE);
```

The response on https://subdomain-b.example.com/showcookie.php is empty.

This works on Firefox, Chrome and Edge.

This must have something to do with how https://subdomain-a.example.com treats iframe content, it works on some instances and on others it does not.

Comment: Did you see any error or warning message in the console? If you change the target value then does it make any difference? For testing purposes, try to lower down the security settings of the IE browser and again try to test the issue. See whether if fix the issue.

Comment: Is there any progress on this issue? If you had found the solution then please try to post it as an answer and try to mark your own answer as an acceptable answer to this question. If the issue still persists then try to refer the suggestions on the thread and let us know about your status for this issue. We will try to provide further suggestions. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT there is no error or warning in the console - I have yet to test the different settings of the IE browser. While changing the IE settings might help temporarily this is not a feasible solution since I don't have any control over the browsers visiting this website.

Comment: It can be possible that your IE has very strict security settings that caused this issue. If you can allow some necessary settings then it can help resolve the issue. I agree with you that you can't control your user's browser settings. You said it does works with some instances. So can you provide more information about it and did you find any difference between them?